# How to handle 404's in GitHub Pages while using Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've setup my site at GitHub using Jekyll framework. I've a problem with 404's. I added a 404.html and it is working well for some typos. But, since in Jekyll categories are rendered in a separate directories and when a user is trying to access the url like `www.example.com/category/` it shows the GitHub's 404 instead of my custom 404.html and also I don't want to index the category so what can I do?

P.S: Added a index.html to each and every category is a good idea. But, while building it overwrites everything in Jekyll. Any tips about that?

Comment: Could you please show a real world example?

Comment: This link has custom 404, right?

Answer (score 11):

This is very late, but I just solved this problem myself and want to help anyone who sees this question later, so the answer is just to put the following snippet:

```
permalink: /404.html
```

in your 404 page's YAML frontmatter.  This tells Jekyll to put the 404 page at that location, where it's automatically recognized as a 404 page.

Comment: It is written in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site

Answer (score 1):

Is your site domain pointing at `108.162.199.32`? Try pointing at `192.30.252.153`, `192.30.252.154`.

Hope this fixes your problem :-)