# How to include a 404 page in Jekyll GitHub pages while using GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to include a 404 page that would be displayed anytime someone navigates to an invalid link for a website that I deployed using GitHub Actions and Jekyll. Still, I don't really understand what to do. I have this GitHub action set up:

```
# Deploying a Jekyll site to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy Product Website

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
    paths:
      - website/**

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Build with Jekyll
        uses: actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
        with:
          source: ./
          destination: ./_site
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: Product website
      url: https://noahweasley.github.io/SMD-Desktop/website
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

and the `404.html` file at the root folder:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Unavailable | S.M.D - Spotify Music Downloader</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/404.css" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="favicon/site.webmanifest" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <nav>
          <ul class="topnav" id="top-nav">
            <div class="logo">
              <a href="./index.html">
                <img src="./assets/app_icon.png" alt="Homepage" width="45px" height="40px" />
              </a>
              <p class="app-name">S.M.D</p>
            </div>
            <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./pages/downloads/get-smd.html">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="./pages/terms.html">Term of use</a></li>
            <li><a href="./pages/privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="./index.html#contact-form-section">Contact Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="./pages/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="./pages/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.patreon.com/noahweasley" target="_blank" id="donate">Donate</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNav()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <main class="content">
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle icon-big"></i>
          <h1 class="heading text-center">Download Unavailable</h1>
          <h3 class="subheading text-center">
            Application is still in development and downloads are not available at the moment
          </h3>
          <a href="https://github.com/noahweasley/SMD-Desktop" class="navigate text-center"> View GitHub Repo </a>
        </main>
    
        <script src="./js/action.js" async defer></script>
    
        <script>
          /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to top nav when the user clicks on the icon */
          function toggleNav() {
            const nav = document.getElementById("top-nav");
            nav.classList.toggle("responsive");
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried a lot of things, I have used the Jekyll front matter; including a `404.md` file as instructed here [Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site), but I can't seem to understand how to set it up. The solutions I have tried work, but doesn't display correctly. I have used something like this:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include 404.html %}
```

And...

```
---
permalink: /404.html
---
```

I also tried these answers; [How to handle 404's in GitHub Pages while using Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973662/how-to-handle-404s-in-github-pages-while-using-jekyll) and [404 page not working with permalink: pretty using GitHub Pages + Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597000/404-page-not-working-with-permalink-pretty-using-github-pages-jekyll) but the resulting 404 page wasn't displaying correctly (its as if the 404.html page displayed over another page)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not displaying correctly?"

Comment: The page displays, but its as if it is displaying over something else

Comment: Sounds like there's something else modifying the HTML page along the way. It would be very helpful if you could provide the source HTML of the rendered page that does not display correctly, or a link to an example

Comment: Ok, I'll add the HTML page, but I doubt that's the issue (I have no idea tho)

Comment: Can you share a link to the rendered page, or the rendered output, or can you put it in a jsfiddle or something? Are you sure you don't have any other github actions enable that would transform your output?

Comment: No, I have only one action that is being run. I'll try to recreate the error and share a screenshot later